# How to send Array of objects to JSON?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am hitting a web service with array of objects. But in server side they are getting only null value for all the fields.

Client side code is:

```
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSURLConnection *connection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                                     delegate:self];
        //************DATA formation
        NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

        [jsonDict setObject:@"3" forKey:@"rollNo"];
        [jsonDict setObject:@"Ezhil" forKey:@"FirstName"];
        [jsonDict setObject:@"Arasu" forKey:@"LastName"];

        [jsonDict1 setObject:@"4" forKey:@"rollNo"];
        [jsonDict1 setObject:@"XYZ" forKey:@"FirstName"];
        [jsonDict1 setObject:@"ABC" forKey:@"LastName"];

        NSArray *jsonArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:jsonDict,jsonDict1, nil];

         //Converting to JSON string.
         SBJsonWriter *writer = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];
         NSString *jsonString = [writer stringWithObject:jsonArray];

         NSLog(@"JSON String : %@",jsonString);

        //************Setting DATA in URL
        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [connection start]; 

        // Code for response....
```

I dont know were i went wrong. Can any one help me for this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd scrap the SBJson stuff and just use the native controls...

Do everything the same as you are doing but remove the SBJsonWriter stuff and do this to set the body of the request...

```
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error]];
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.. Application is working fine without any modification. The problem is with server side. But i think we can go with your suggestion instead of using external framework.

In both the case I am getting the json object like this,

```
JSON String : 
 [{"rollNo":"3","FirstName":"Ezhil","LastName":"Arasu"},
  {"rollNo":"4","FirstName":"XYZ","LastName":"ABC"}]
```